# BigQuery external tables with python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

How can i create external tables (federated data source) in BigQuery using python (google-cloud-bigquery)?

I know you can use bq commands like this, but that is not how i want to do it:

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=path/to/json tablename
bq update tablename path/to/schemafile

with external_table_definition as:
{
  "autodetect": true,
  "maxBadRecords": 9999999,
  "csvOptions": {
    "skipLeadingRows": 1
  },
  "sourceFormat": "CSV",
  "sourceUris": [
    "gs://bucketname/file_*.csv"
  ]
}
```

and a schemafile like this:

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE", 
    "name": "mycolumn1", 
    "type": "INTEGER"
  }, 
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE", 
    "name": "mycolumn2", 
    "type": "STRING"
  }, 
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE", 
    "name": "mycolumn3", 
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

Thank you for your help!
Lars

Comment: Is this what you need? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#creating_a_permanent_external_table

It has 4 options: Classic UI, CLI, API and Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table_id = 'table1'

table = bigquery.Table(dataset_ref.table(table_id), schema=schema)
external_config = bigquery.ExternalConfig('CSV')
external_config = {
  "autodetect": true,
  "options": {
    "skip_leading_rows": 1
  },
  "source_uris": [
    "gs://bucketname/file_*.csv"
  ]
}
table.external_data_configuration = external_config
table = client.create_table(table)
```

Schema Format is :

```
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField(name='mycolumn1', field_type='INTEGER', is_nullable=True),
    bigquery.SchemaField(name='mycolumn2', field_type='STRING', is_nullable=True),
    bigquery.SchemaField(name='mycolumn3', field_type='STRING', is_nullable=True),
]
```

Comment: How does the second assignment of the variable `external_config` not wipe out the first? You are not updating the config here, you are replacing the `bigquery.ExternalConfig` object simply with a `dict`. Additionally the `T` in `true` must be capitalized. This code snippet does not run at all, it raises a `ValueError` when you run `table.external_data_configuration = external_config`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is well after the question has been asked and answered, but the above accepted answer does not work. I attempted to do the same thing you are describing and additionally trying to use the same approach to update an existing external table who added some new columns. This would be the correct snippet to use assuming you have that JSON file stored somewhere like `/tmp/schema.json`

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE", 
    "name": "mycolumn1", 
    "type": "INTEGER"
  }, 
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE", 
    "name": "mycolumn2", 
    "type": "STRING"
  }, 
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE", 
    "name": "mycolumn3", 
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

You should simply need to have the following if you already have the API representation of the options you want to add to the external table.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

# dataset must exist first
dataset_name = 'some_dataset'
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_name)

table_name = 'tablename'

# Or wherever your json schema lives
schema = client.schema_from_json('/tmp/schema.json')

external_table_options = {
  "autodetect": True,
  "maxBadRecords": 9999999,
  "csvOptions": {
    "skipLeadingRows": 1
  },
  "sourceFormat": "CSV",
  "sourceUris": [
    "gs://bucketname/file_*.csv"
  ]
}

external_config = client.ExternalConfig.from_api_repr(external_table_options)

table = bigquery.Table(dataset_ref.table(table_name), schema=schema)
table.external_data_configuration = external_config

client.create_table(
    table,

    # Now you can create the table safely with this option
    # so that it does not fail if the table already exists
    exists_od=True

)

# And if you seek to update the table's schema and/or its
# external options through the same script then use
client.update_table(
    table,

    # As a side note, this portion of the code had me confounded for hours.
    # I could not for the life of me figure our that "fields" did not point
    # to the table's columns, but pointed to the `google.cloud.bigquery.Table`
    # object's attributes. IMHO, the naming of this parameter is horrible
    # given "fields" are already a thing (i.e. `SchemaField`s).
    fields=['schema', 'external_data_configuration'])
)
```

In addition to setting the external table configuration using the API representation, you can set all of the same attributes by calling the names of those attributes on the `bigquery.ExternalConfig` object itself. So this would be another approach surrounding just the `external_config` portion of the code above.

```py
external_config = bigquery.ExternalConfig('CSV')
external_config.autodetect = True
external_config.max_bad_records = 9999999
external_config.options.skip_leading_rows = 1
external_config.source_uris = ["gs://bucketname/file_*.csv"]
```

I must again however raise some frustration with the Google documentation. The `bigquery.ExternalConfig.options` attribute *claims* that it can be set with a dictionary

```py
>>> from google.cloud import bigquery
>>> help(bigquery.ExternalConfig.options)
Help on property:

    Optional[Dict[str, Any]]: Source-specific options.
```

but that is *completely false*. As you can see above the python object attribute names and the API representation names of those same attributes are slightly different. Either way you try it though, if you had a dict of the source-specific options (e.g. `CSVOptions`, `GoogleSheetsOptions`, `BigTableOptions`, etc...) and attempted to pass that dict as the `options` attribute, it laughs in your face and says mean things like this.

```
>>> from google.cloud import bigquery
>>> external_config = bigquery.ExternalConfig('CSV')
>>> options = {'skip_leading_rows': 1}
>>> external_config.options = options
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: cant set attribute
>>> options = {'skipLeadingRows': 1}
>>> external_config.options = options
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: cant set attribute
>>> options = {'CSVOptions': {'skip_leading_rows': 1}}
>>> external_config.options = options
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: cant set attribute
>>> options = {'CSVOptions': {'skipLeadingRows': 1}}
>>> external_config.options = options
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: cant set attribute
```

The workaround was iterating over the `options` dict and using the `__setattr__()` method on the options which worked well for me. Pick you favorite approach from above. I have tested all of this code and will be using it for some time.

Comment: I was using the library version `google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0` FWIW